# |$\frac{z-w}{1-\bar zw}$| $=1$ when $|z|=1$ or $|w|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Assuming either $|z|=1$ or $|w|=1$ , prove that

|$\frac{z-w}{1-\bar zw}$| $=1$

When assuming that only $|z|=1$, we can easily deduce that $|{z-w}|=|{1-\bar zw}|$

But it's more complicated when we take the case where only $|w|=1$

Any hints please ?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: In reality, we can easily deduce $z-w=z(1-\bar zw)$, if $|z|=1$.

Comment: It is "more complicated", you say? How so? The function is symmetrical!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|w|=1$, then$$\left|1-\overline zw\right|=\left|\overline ww-\overline zw\right|=\left|\overline w-\overline z\right|.\left|w\right|=|w-z|=|z-w|.$$

Comment: it should read "if $|w|=1$,..."

Comment: @ProfessorVector I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Did you multiply by z after the second equal?

Comment: @Karen I made a mistake but I've already edited my answer. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

A series of algebraical manipulations show that
$$
\frac{\lvert{w-z}\rvert}{\lvert{1 - \overline{w}z}\rvert} \leq 1
$$
if and only if
\begin{align*}
\lvert{w-z\rvert}^2 \leq \lvert{1 - \overline{w}z\rvert}^2 
&\iff \lvert{w\rvert}^2 - \overline{w}z - w\overline{z} +\lvert{z\rvert}^2 \leq 1-\overline{w}z-w\overline{z} + \lvert{w}^2\rvert{z}^2 \\
&\iff 0 \leq (1-\lvert{w\rvert})(1-\lvert{z\rvert})
\end{align*}
Indeed, the above inequality holds whenever $\lvert{w\rvert}, \lvert{z\rvert} \leq 1$. Furthermore, we have a strict inequality if $\lvert{w\rvert}, \lvert{z\rvert} < 1$ and equality if $\lvert{z\rvert} = 1$ or $\lvert{w\rvert}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $|w|=1$, then $|\bar{w}|=1$, therefore $$|1-\bar{z}w|=|1-\bar{z}w|\cdot|\bar{w}|=|\bar{w}-|w|^2\bar{z}|=|\bar{w}-\bar{z}|=|w-z|$$